# TYPO3 v10.2: Frontend user session saving ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user) in Custom Authentication Service

Tags: authentication, session, typo3, middleware, extbase

Right now I am upgrading an old pibased Extension from 6.2 to an extbase 10.2 Extension.
After some research I found out that the Request Workflow for Frontend Requests has changed in TYPO3 10.0 (Issue #88540).
From the Changelog:

> TSFE is instantiated after all site resolving, authentication, page
>   resolving and argument validation is done.

Since I used to store user sessions in `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user` with `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses','key', $value)` while authentication process (Custom authService) I am not able to store it anymore because of the changed request workflow. `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user` is now instantiated after the authentication process. It seems like that saving frontend user session has to be moved into Middleware (found some Information here: Task #88541). Since I never dealt with Middlewares, my Question now is how I can achive saving my frontend user session data by using a middleware Class?  Under `Configuration\RequestMiddlewares.php` I got following config:

```
return [
    'frontend' => [
        'my-middleware-identifier' => [
            'target' => \Vendor\Extension\Middleware\Session::class,
            'after' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/prepare-tsfe-rendering'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TYPO3 v10.0.0 the Request Workflow for Frontend Requests has changed. That's why it isn't possible anymore to store session data during the authentication process. See: [Changed Request Workflow for Frontend Requests](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-88540-ChangedRequestWorkflowForFrontendRequests.html) I used a custom middleware for this to store it after the `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user` has been created.